# How to list all json key from LogEntry in azure KQL

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm using azure log analytics workspace for crating azure monitoring workbooks.

Here is one parameter I have to create which will present All json key from LogEntry.

e.g. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3kvX.png)

LogEntry has details of @metadata, @timestamp and other keys.

Which operator I should use for getting all Json key under LogEntry.

I try below steps but there is no such a sub module it's showing.

`ContainerLog | project LogEntry | evaluate bag_unpack(LogEntry)`

I was reffering [link](https://www.systemcenterautomation.com/2020/01/extracting-nested-fields-kusto/) but this parameters is not working in log analytics.

Comment: it would help if you could include a small sample input (as text, instead of as an image), and the expected output that matches that input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not mentioned in the blog you referenced, the `bag_unpack` plugin can be used in Azure Application Insights Workbooks as well.

[image: Application Insights Workbooks Example]

However, I'm afraid it won't work on the table in question, the reason being, `bag_unpack(column)` expects the `column` argument to be a reference to a **dynamic** column, whereas the *LogEntry* column in [ContainerLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/containerlog) table is of type **string**.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/containerlog